# Listing users in rails +template error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am starting my learning process by first listing all the users.

First I had added an action in the controller as

```
def list_users
  @users=User.find(:all)
end
```

And in the View `users/list_users.html.erb` I have added the line

`list_users.html.erb`:

```
<%= Time.now %>

<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.firstname %>
<% end %>
```

And for routing I have added the routes as

```
map.list_users '/list_users', :controller => 'users', :action => 'list_users'
```

That's it .. when I run my app , it's showing me the error as

```
     Development mode eh? Here is the error - #<ActionView::TemplateError: 
     ActionView::TemplateError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
      You might have expected an instance of Array.
      The error occurred while evaluating nil.each) on line #7 of app/views/users/list_users.html.erb:
```

Why so?

---

Solution:

I myself find that the controller action is under protected, that's why it showed me the error.

Comment: You're calling a method that does not exist, as the error states. Without more context, that's as much as anyone will be able to tell you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you didn't use the `login` method in `list_users.html.erb`, where did you used it?

But here is another error (maybe typo error only?)

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.firstname # not @user here! %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Still i am getting the same error..
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each) on line #7 of app/views/users/list_users.html.erb: -- EVEN AFTER CHANGING THE @user to user.firstname..

Comment: So it's complaining `@users` is null...Could you provide more codes in your controller and you view?